# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on 30" Monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio 2008 SP1 runs really slow on my 30" Monitor, is anyone else having this issue or have a fix for this? What I mean by runs slow, is when I scroll or start typing something, it takes a little while for it to respond. When I put it on my smaller monitor (24" or smaller) it works perfect.  This is on Windows 7.

EDIT: Sorry guys, I didn't think my specs were relevant since I heard that other people were having the same issue.  I have a Core 2 Duo 2.0, with 3 GB of RAM and I have a PCI express 1GB RAM video card (that can run up to 2 30" monitors (dual-link dvi)).

Answer (score 4):

Have you installed the Monitor Vendor specific display drivers?

I have a 20" LG flatscreen which worked well with built in XP drivers. But once I installed the vendor provided Display drivers, I could see a markable difference.

Also is your configuration good enough for Windows 7 (good Graphics card, good processor , 2GB + RAM?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that issue here.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.30729.1 SP and am running on a DELL 2007WFP 30" LCD Monitor with a NVIDIA Quadro FX 370 display adapter.

Machine is 2.4GHZ Intel Quad Core CPU.
I used to be running 32-bit Vista with 4GB of memory. 
Now am running 64-bit Windows Seven with 8GB of memory.
With both configurations, VS performs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the same, but I have run Visual Studio 2008 on a computer with a 24" monitor and a 22" monitor before and it ran fine. I dragged all of the 'tool' windows like the Solution Explorer off to the second monitor and had a split code view on the other. It worked perfectly with 4GB RAM and a 2.8GHz Core 2 Duo. Plus, productivity was much better!

Answer (score 1):

You don't say now much memory your system has or what graphics card you are using. You also don't give the resolution of the display either.

The step from 24" to 30" is quite large and would require a relatively large amount of memory.

It could be that your graphics card/chip isn't up to the task as has had to revert to software rendering rather than using the hardware acceleration. You could also be running out of memory.

Comment: It could be quite slow especially if you're running on an integrated graphics "card", that generally doesn't have that much memory. You could install a dedicated graphics card with more memory (or borrow one) and see if that helped.